# How to change default log location of SMF registered processes

Tags: solaris

I am trying to change default log location ( var/svc/logs/) of each and every SMF registered processes and append to particular file (/opt/smf.log).

Comment: @Banti are you referring to this [Service Management Facility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Management_Facility) ? SMF is an ambiguous acronym, which also means [Simple Machines Forum](http://www.simplemachines.org/).

Comment: @xenoterracide Actually i had posted this question in solaris so, SMF should be considered as Service management facility :)

Comment: @Gyan answers are not comments ;) . I migrated it.

Answer (score 2):

That file path appears to be compiled into svc.startd:

```
myhostname# strings /lib/svc/bin/svc.startd |grep '/var/svc/log'
/var/svc/log/
/var/svc/log/
/var/svc/log/
/var/svc/log/
```

I suppose you could try changing the location of the *directory* to somewhere else, and make `/var/svc/log` a symlink to the new location, but I don't believe it's possible to make the services all log to one file -- that's just not how SMF was designed to work.  And since svc.startd starts early in the boot process, before /var is even mounted read-write, linking `/var/svc/log` to some other -- possibly even unmounted -- partition may cause trouble.